# Deleting a Row from JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I am deleting the row from the table using `fnDeleteRow` function but the problem is that it deletes the correct row for the first time only and than start deleting the next row instead of that for which I am pressing the delete button.

**here is my code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).delegate('.but', 'click', function() { 

            var id = this.id; //getting the ID of the pressed button
            var name = this.name; //getting the name of the pressed button

            /****AJAX Function*********/
            $.post('/products/delete', {id:id}, function(data) {
                if(data == 1){ //In case if data is deleted

                    var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable(); // JQuery dataTable function to delete the row from the table
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow( parseInt(name, 10) );// JQuery dataTable function to delete the row from the table
                  //  oTable.fnDraw(true);



               }
                else
                    alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

`this.name`     gives the row number of the row associated with the pressed button as I don't know any method to calculate the rowIndex dynamically from the dataTable.

As I calculate the row number on the server side and associate that number with the button, so when I delete the row datatable rearranges its rowIndex on client side and server does not know any thing regard this.

Any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).delegate('.but', 'click', function() { 

            var id = this.id; //getting the ID of the pressed button
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);

            /****AJAX Function*********/
            $.post('/products/delete', {id:id}, function(data) {
                if(data == 1){ //In case if data is deleted

                    var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable(); // JQuery dataTable function to delete the row from the table
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(row));// JQuery dataTable function to delete the row from the table
                  //  oTable.fnDraw(true);
               }
                else
                    alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Delete Row from dataTable - START //
    $('body').on('click', 'i.DeleteRow', function() {
          DeletedRow = $(this).parents('tr');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.btnYES', function(){
        console.log('DeletedRow:', DeletedRow);
        $('#unitsTableDisplay').DataTable().row(DeletedRow).remove().draw();
    })
    // Delete Row from dataTable - END //
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-new-button').on('click',function(){
        var rData = [
            test1,
            test1,
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
         $('#dataTable').DataTable().row.add(rData).draw(false);
    });

   $('#dataTable').on('click', '.update', function () {
        var pageParamTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
        var rData = [
            test1,
            test1,
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
        pageParamTable
                .row( tableRow )
                .data(rData)
                .draw();
    });
    $('#dataTable').on('click', '.delete', function () {
       var pageParamTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
        pageParamTable.row( tableRow ).remove().draw();
    });
});
```

in this code you can find delete, add and update row from a DataTable it works for our peoject